# Put a picture between two text (Arab)

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, arabic, arabxetex

How to prut an image between these two text

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{arabbook}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{arqam}
%\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{minitoc}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setarab
\novocalize
\parindent=0pt
\textwidth=23truecm
\hoffset=-5truecm
\textheight=30cm
\voffset=-5cm
\begin{document}


%\vspace{-20cm}

\hspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\begin{large}
\begin{center}

\AR{\textyerm{وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي}}\\
\AR{\textthol{المدرسة العليا للأساتذة}}\\
 \AR{\textmash{$-$ القبة القديمة $-$ (الجزائر)}}\\
 \AR{\textbattar{قسم الرياضيات}}
\end{center}
\end{large}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}{1cm}

\end{minipage}
\hspace{0cm}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{large}
\begin{center}

{\em Minist\`ere de l'Enseignement Sup\'erieur}\\
{\em et de la Recherche Scientifique} \\
\textrm{ \'Ecole Normale Sup\'erieure}\\
-Vieux Kouba- (Alger)\\
\textmd{ D\'epartement de Math\'ematiques} \\
\end{center}
\end{large}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code, removing packages that were not needed for the example. You can change margins etc. according to your needs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\selectlanguage{french}
\hspace{-1.5cm}
\thead{
\textit{Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur}\\%
\textit{et de la Recherche Scientifique} \\
École Normale Supérieure\\
Vieux Kouba -- Alger\\
Département de Mathématiques
}
&
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
&
\thead{
\AR{\textyerm{وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي}}\\
\AR{\textthol{المدرسة العليا للأساتذة}}\\
 \AR{\textmash{$-$ القبة القديمة $-$ (الجزائر)}}\\
 \AR{\textbattar{قسم الرياضيات}}
}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3cm}

وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to add

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```

into the empty minipage environment, after that you change the code

```
\voffset=-5cm
```

to

```
\voffset=-3.5cm
```

it comes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{arqam}
%\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{minitoc}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setarab
\novocalize
\parindent=0pt
\textwidth=23truecm
\hoffset=-5truecm
\textheight=30cm
\voffset=-3.5cm
\begin{document}


%\vspace{-20cm}

\hspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\begin{large}
\begin{center}
```

It will compile very well as follows:

[image: output]